# How to get ID using a specific word in regex?

Tags: php, regex

**My string:**

```
<div class="sect1" id="s9781473910270.i101">       
<div class="sect2" id="s9781473910270.i102">
<h1 class="title">1.2 Summations and Products[label*summation]</h1>
<p>text</p> 
</div>
</div>           
<div class="sect1" id="s9781473910270.i103">
<p>sometext [ref*summation]</p>
</div>

<div class="figure" id="s9781473910270.i220">
<div class="metadata" id="s9781473910270.i221">
</div>
<p>fig1.2 [label*somefigure]</p>
<p>sometext [ref*somefigure]</p>
</div>
```

**Objective:** 1.In the string above `label*string` and `ref*string` are the cross references. In the place of `[ref*string]` I need to replace with `a` with the atributes of `class` and `href`, href is the id of `div` where related `label*` resides. And class of `a` is the class of `div`

2. As I mentioned above `a` element class and ID is their relative `div` class names and ID. But if `div class="metadata"` exists, need to ignore it should not take their class name and ID.

**Expected output:**

```
<div class="sect1" id="s9781473910270.i101">       
<div class="sect2" id="s9781473910270.i102">
<h1 class="title">1.2 Summations and Products[label*summation]</h1>
<p>text</p> 
</div>
</div>             
<div class="sect1" id="s9781473910270.i103">
<p>sometext <a class="section-ref" href="s9781473910270.i102">1.2</a></p>
</div>


<div class="figure" id="s9781473910270.i220">
<div class="metadata" id="s9781473910270.i221">
<p>fig1.2 [label*somefigure]</p>
</div>
<p>sometext <a class="fig-ref" href="s9781473910270.i220">fig 1.2</a></p>          
</div>
```

How to do it in simpler way without using DOM parser?

My idea is, have to store `label* string` and their ID in an array and will loop against ref string to match the `label* string` if string matches then their related id and class should be replaced in the place of `ref* string` , 
So I have tried [this](https://regex101.com/r/zK8mR8/2) regex to get `label*string` and their related id and class name.

Comment: The simple way **is** to use a DOM parser.

Comment: Could you provide an example with well formed html (to see exactly where div tags are closed in particular)?

Comment: Actually If I use DOM parser the result will be saved as HTML only,  but I don't need to save the result into HTML after manipulation.

Comment: Whatever the way you use the result is always saved as a string!

Comment: Have updated post with proper HTML format

Comment: I don't understand why the second created link has the id `s9781473910270.i220` since the id of the nearest parent div where is the label `[label*somefigure]` is `s9781473910270.i221`. Second question, why in your example the links don't have the classname of the divs? And to finish, from where comes the text content enclosed by links?

Comment: For quesion 1. If the nearest div class is metadata then have to ignore it and should take another div which is just above the metadata class div. Then 2. if class name of div is `sect` or `figure` then `a` elements class name should be like `section-ref` or `fig-ref`. And 3. The content of `a` comes from `>1.2 Summations and Products[label*summation]` (i.e. in the line of `label* ` have to capture the string between `>` and first space character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach consists to use the html structure to retrieve needed elements with DOMXPath. Regex are used in a second time to extract informations from text nodes or attributes:

```
$classRel = ['sect2'  => 'section-ref',
             'figure' => 'fig-ref'];

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html); // or $dom->loadHTMLFile($url); 

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

// make a custom php function available for the XPath query
// (it isn't really necessary, but it is more rigorous than writing
// "contains(@class, 'myClass')" )
$xp->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");

function hasClass($classNode, $className) {
    if (!empty($classNode))
        return in_array($className, preg_split('~\s+~', $classNode[0]->value, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
    return false;
}

$xp->registerPHPFunctions('hasClass');


// The XPath query will find the first ancestor of a text node with '[label*'
// that is a div tag with an id and a class attribute,
// if the class attribute doesn't contain the "metadata" class.

$labelQuery = <<<'EOD'
//text()[contains(., 'label*')]
/ancestor::div
[@id and @class and not(php:function('hasClass', @class, 'metadata'))][1]
EOD;

$idNodeList = $xp->query($labelQuery);

$links = [];

// For each div node, a new link node is created in the associative array $links.
// The keys are labels. 
foreach($idNodeList as $divNode) {

    // The pattern extract the first text part in group 1 and the label in group 2
    if (preg_match('~(\S+) .*? \[label\* ([^]]+) ]~x', $divNode->textContent, $m)) {
        $links[$m[2]] = $dom->createElement('a');
        $links[$m[2]]->setAttribute('href', $divNode->getAttribute('id'));
        $links[$m[2]]->setAttribute('class', $classRel[$divNode->getAttribute('class')]);
        $links[$m[2]]->nodeValue = $m[1];
    }
}


if ($links) { // if $links is empty no need to do anything

    $refNodeList = $xp->query("//text()[contains(., '[ref*')]");

    foreach ($refNodeList as $refNode) {
        // split the text with square brackets parts, the reference name is preserved in a capture
        $parts = preg_split('~\[ref\*([^]]+)]~', $refNode->nodeValue, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

        // create a fragment to receive text parts and links
        $frag = $dom->createDocumentFragment();

        foreach ($parts as $k=>$part) {
            if ($k%2 && isset($links[$part])) { // delimiters are always odd items
                $clone = $links[$part]->cloneNode(true);
                $frag->appendChild($clone);
            } elseif ($part !== '') {
                $frag->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($part));
            }
        }

        $refNode->parentNode->replaceChild($frag, $refNode);
    }
}

$result = '';

$childNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes;

foreach ($childNodes as $childNode) {
    $result .= $dom->saveXML($childNode);
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm and thanks again for your valuable time spent.  But one query If I use `saveHTML` mehtod then `HTML and body` tags are wrapped with the string. I need to eliminate it. I need only input string as the output not extra tags. What to do for tat?

Comment: @Learning: there are options you can pass to `DOMDocument::loadHTML` to avoid this automatic behaviour (same for the DOCTYPE). `$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);`. But when you use that, your html must have a root element, so change `$html` to `'<div>' . $html . '</div>'`, and remove the root element with `substr` at the end.

Comment: And another problem is, using `DOM`, it changes the input string for example `<br />` to `<br>` `<img /> to `<img >` . I don't need any changes in the output.

Comment: @Learning: This is important only if your piece of html must be strict xhtml compliant (if it is html5 or xhtml transitional, it doesn't matter)  .  in this case remove `loadHTML` options and the root div, and see my edit that uses `DOMDocument::saveXML` to concatenate each body children to the result string. In this way you obtain self-closing tags in xml style (note that `<br>` will be changed to `<br/>`).

Comment: Another issue :(   The replacement link in the place of `ref*` doesn't work if it is repeated.  Only replacement worked at the last occcurrence. If the string like this `$html='<div class="sect1" id="s9781473910270.i101">       
<p>sometext [ref*summation]</p>
<div class="sect1" id="s9781473910270.i102">
<h1 class="title">1.2 Summations and Products[label*summation]</h1>
<p>text</p> 
</div>    
<div class="sect1" id="s9781473910270.i103">
<p>sometext [ref*summation]</p>
</div>
</div>'`- if `ref*string` repeated twice, link is created only at the last occurrence. I tried to fix it, but no luck.

Comment: And also if nested div has two label in it then `ref*` is not converted in to links for example : `<div class="sect1" id="s9781473910270.i159">
<h1 class="title">1.1 Solving Equations and Inequalities[label*solving]</h1>
<div class="sect2" id="s9781473910270.i160">
<h2 class="title">Isolating a Variable[label*isovar]</h2></div></div>
`

Comment: @Learning: With your system, several ref with the same label has no-sense, since you will create tags with the same id attribute (an id attribute must be unique). In this context, I have assumed, that there's no need to create several link nodes for the same label. But when there are several ref for the same label, the first ref is correctly replaced, but after (since it is the same node), the link node is moved to the second and so on.

Comment: @Learning: It can be easily solved, if you clone the link node before appending it to the fragment. (see `DOMNode::cloneNode` in php manual). However, if you do that, you will create invalid html.

Comment: @Learning: for the two labels in nested div, I have edited the xpath query (more simple).

Comment: actually link does not have Id...its `href`, so no problem will be created if links are repeated.

Comment: I modified your program  like this `$links[$m[2]]->setAttribute('href', "#".$divNode->getAttribute('id'));Since it has no ID in it, HTML  still wil be valid.
`

Answer (score -1):

This is not a task for regular expressions. Regular expressions are (usually) for regular languages. And what you want to do is some work on a context sensitive language (referencing an identifier which has been declared before).

So you should definately go with a DOM parser. The algorithm for this would be very easy, because you can operate on one node and it's children.

So the theoretical answer to your question is: you can't. Though it might work out with the many regex extensions in some crappy way.

Comment: How to do it using DOM parser?